# How to map an xml sequence of mixed elements to a go struct?

Tags: xml, go, sequence

'm trying to load an XML file that contains an unbounded sequence of mixed elements (a choice in a sequence in the XSD)
The file looks like that :

```
<RootNode>
    <ElementB>...</ElementB>
    <ElementA>...</ElementA>
    <ElementA>...</ElementA>
    <ElementC>...</ElementC>
    <ElementB>...</ElementB>
    <ElementA>...</ElementA>
    <ElementB>...</ElementB>
</RootNode>
```

I use xml.Unmarshal to initialize and fill these structs :

```
type RootNode struct {
    ElementA []ElementA
    ElementB []ElementB
    ElementC []ElementC
}

type ElementA struct {
}

type ElementB struct {
}

type ElementC struct {
}
```

I have working exemple here http://play.golang.org/p/ajIReJS35F.
The problem is that i need to know the index of the elements in the original sequence. And with that description, this info is lost.

Is there a way to to load elements of type ElementA, ElementB or ElementC in the same array ? More generally, what is the best way to map a list of mixed elements to a go struct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xml:",any"` tag on your root node and then unmarshal the rest into structs that have an `XMLName` field like this:

```
type RootNode struct {
    Elements []Element `xml:",any"`
}

type Element struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
}
```

More on `xml:",any"` and `XMLName` [here](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal).

Playground example: http://play.golang.org/p/Vl9YI8GG1E